# R choroplethrzip package: Modifying scale and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, choroplethr

I am trying to use this package in R to do a map:
https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip

Example code shows like this:

```
choro = ZipChoropleth$new(zip)
choro$set_zoom_zip(state_zoom='california', county_zoom=NULL,
                   msa_zoom=NULL, zip_zoom=NULL)
choro$title = 'My cool title'
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="", palette=5, drop=FALSE)
choro$render()
```

Works wonderfully well. But, I am trying to modify the default scale and the legend display using the breaks as follows. But, this does not seem to do anything.

Anyone know how scale_fill_brewer + discrete_scale can be combined together to make a custom fill scale and legend with choroplethrZip? I have data that has the zip column and a value column as the package expects.

```
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(breaks = c(1, 100, 1000, 5000,
10000, 50000, 100000), guide = "legend", name="Georgia Base",         
palette=5, drop=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ari - the author of the package was kind enough to help with the issue here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/choroplethr/DWLFWEKwJKA

It requires custom cutting the data into different quantiles and feeding them as level values to the package.

Comment: it appears ths group no longer exists or requires permission to view....I'm looking to do something similar.  I'm creating a county level map and I have a couple of counties whose values are orders of magnitude larger than anyone else, and it throws the whole scale off.